# ReverseGeocodeLocation City not accurate enough

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gps, location

I'm receiving an array of placemarks from :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    ..
}
```

when printing to console using `NSLog`, the placemark gives me data in the form of:

> ..HIDDEN.. St., **Brighton**, MA  02135, United States @
>   <+42.HIDDEN,-71.HIDDEN> +/- 100.00m

But when using the following code, I get **Boston** as the city

```
[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*)kABPersonAddressCityKey]);
```

Brighton is a part of Boston, but how can the console log be showing me a more specific location than the City key..?

Comment: offhand, it looks like locationManager may be using a closer CLLocationAccuracy value.

Comment: Placemarks also have a [`subLocality`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/subLocality) property, which, where possible, contains more specific information like the name of a neighborhood/borough/district within a city -- that might be what the `description` logging to the console uses, which would explain why you see Brighton even when the city is Boston.

Comment: So i thought that would be the case, but subLocality gives another _more specific_ location, not Brighton or Boston.  I still haven't found where the `description` is getting Brighton from

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best you can do with placemarks is

```
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
```

This post may be of some use [iOS: get Accurate Reverse Geocoding using CLLocationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127405/ios-get-accurate-reverse-geocoding-using-cllocationmanager)

It's also worth noting that using Boston in place of Brighton is still a valid address for the same location.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1975

This worked for me:

```
- (void) resetLocationData{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"LAT: %f", [locationManager location].coordinate.latitude);
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [locationManager location].coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [locationManager location].coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *latlong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitude, longitude];
    NSLog(@"LONG: %f", [locationManager location].coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"Combined Location: %@", latlong);

    [[locationManager location]timestamp];
}


#pragma mark - CLLOCATION STUFF
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {

         NSLog(@"Placemark is %@", placemarks);
         CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"placemark 0: %@", place);

        // locationLabel.text = placemarks;

     }];
    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

**LOG OUTPUT:**

2013-01-13 23:23:05.508 CLLocationTest[47617:907] Placemark is (
    "XX XXXXXX Rd, XX XXXXXX Rd, Brighton, MA  02135, United States @ <+42.XXXXXX,-71.XXXXXXX> +/- 100.00m"

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is how printing the placemark via nslog is showing the accurate city. Where is this getting the city from?